# Is there a way to improve this SQL query to retrive data in a certain order?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with the 2 following tables

posts:

```
|post_id| text |post_date(time_stamp)|
```

likes:

```
| like_id | likee (1 or -1) | post_id | like_date (time_stamp) |
```

I am trying to recover all posts that were liked in the past hour and order them by how many likes they received in the past hour.

I tried the following query which returned all posts that were liked in the past hour, but I haven't been able to figure out how to order the by the sum of likee per post_id.

```
SELECT * FROM posts
  INNER JOIN likes ON posts.post_id = likes.post_id
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,like_time,NOW())< 1 AND likee= 1
```

is there any way I can achieve it by modifying the query?

Comment: Sounds like you need an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: You can't order by an aggregate value in a query that doesn't have any aggregation.  Not a MySql expert at all, but you may be able to order by `sum(likee) over (partition by post_id)`.

Comment: Yep. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - also, I have a feeling that timestampdiff is not the most efficient method

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: `how many likes`  mean Up Votes or UpVotes - DownVotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate the likes (or positive likes) on the last hour:

```
 SELECT post_id, 
        SUM( likee ) as total_likes,
        SUM( CASE WHEN likee = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as total_positive_likes
 FROM likes
 WHERE like_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
 GROUP BY post_id;
```

Notice you don't change the field `like_date` instead you create a constant from `NOW()` that way you can use index.

Now you join your post with total likes

```
SELECT p.*, l.total_likes
FROM Post p 
JOIN ( SELECT post_id, 
              SUM( likee ) as total_likes,
              SUM( CASE WHEN likee = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as total_positive_likes
       FROM likes
       WHERE like_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
       GROUP BY post_id
    ) L
  ON p.post_id = l.post_id
ORDER BY l.total_likes DESC
```

Comment: Yes, doing subselect on likes table with date filter first should improve performance.

Comment: Why not just add "ORDER BY total_positive_likes" to the first query?

Comment: @oysteing Because the outer query would be small so sort would be quicker. Also, sort order isn't always warranted so is better do the sort at the end.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry, I misread the inner query, and thought that it did a join of both tables.  Ordering in the subquery does of course not make sense.  What I meant to say, was that I am not convinced that using a derived table will perform better than just joining the two original tables, and sort the result.

Comment: @oysteing Yes you could do that, but then you would have to `GROUP BY` for every column of Post. My main idea was separate the steps so the process was more clear for the OP.  Also not sure if would be any big difference in performance.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Since MySQL 5.7, columns that are functionally dependent on the GROUP BY columns can be included in the select list.  So when grouping on the primary key, any columns from that table may be included even if they are not in GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INNER JOIN likes ON posts.post_id = likes.post_id
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,like_time,NOW())< 1 AND likee= 1
ORDER BY likee DESC
```

You can do this using `ORDER BY` statement. @[Mysql basics](https://blog.philippdalheimer.de/2019/08/27/database-the-mysql-basics/)

Comment: If `likee  = 1`, what `ORDER BY likee DESC` does?

Comment: ops, I thought 'likee' is the like's value. I think it's just the indicator that a post was liked (?) If so, the ORDER BY has to be the value of likes in likes table